# VF page Command button Rerender issue loading JQUERY

Tags: visualforce, jquery

VF Page:

```
    <div class="modal-footer">                             
    <apex:commandButton id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" action="{!accountWrapperObject}" reRender="datePanelContainer" />
</div>
<apex:outputpanel id="studentTable" >
      <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer"> 
            <table id="domainTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped"> 
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAllDomainList" checked="" />
                                       <label for="selectAllDomainList"> Select All  </label>
                                 </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>Student Engagement</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                          <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/> 
                                  <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">  
                                       <tr> 
                                          <td> 
                                              <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                                  <input id="Text{!rowNum}" type="checkbox" checked=""/>
                                                        <label for="Text{!rowNum}"> Primary </label>
                                                        </div>
                                          </td>   
                                          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Site__c}" /></td>
                                        </tr>                                             
                                     <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{! rowNum + 1 }"/> 
                               </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  


         jQuery(function($){                        
            $('#selectAllDomainList').click (function () {
                 var checkedStatus = this.checked;
                $('#domainTable tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
                 });
            });
        }); 
     </script>
```

Issue:

Issue with command button rerender. reRender="datePanelContainer". If I use this, SelectAll check box Jquery function does not fire and it will not check all the checkboxes.

Can anyone help me where I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

JQUERY:

```
<script>
        function addListener() {
            $('#selectAllDomainList').click (function () {
                 var checkedStatus = this.checked;
                $('#domainTable tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
                 });
            });
        }
        // Add listener when page loads
        addListener();
     </script>
```

Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the function to

```
function testFuntion(t){    
      var checkedStatus = t.checked;
                $('#domainTable tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
                 });

     }
```

And I called this function on SelectAllcheckbox

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `apex:commandButton:`

```
oncomplete="addListener()"
```

and change the JavaScript to this:

```
<script>
function addListener() {
    // Put your existing jQuery code in here
}
// Add listener when page loads
addListener();
</script>
```

so that the jQuery logic is applied to the page elements both when the page loads and when the re-render is complete and there are new elements added to the page.

Comment: Added oncomplete event to command button and also updated Jquery, now when click button nothing is happening, means controller method is not getting called. Please see my post with updated Jquery as you suggested. Regards, Ajay